# What is this story with three humanoid robots that looked realistic?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching this about 5 or 6 years ago.

It was a live action show with a few seasons, about this family with this inventor guy and his wife and son. He lived in a house that was very integrated with technology.

In his basement he had these three teenagers who were part robot and had powers, but they looked just like humans, and the story was about the three teenagers trying to fit in at the local high school with the inventor's kid helping them. I also remember there being something about bionics.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Lab Rats](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1991564/)

> A scrawny 14-year-old, having discovered his inventor stepdad has
> three bionic, super-powered teens living cloistered in a secret lab
> beneath their home, brings them out into the world.

It aired on Disney XD from February 27, 2012 to February 3, 2016.

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Thank you!

Comment: It was the first result from Google:  "three teenage cyborg basement tv"

Comment: Ah, I could only find "My Life as a Teenage Robot" and "Teen Titans Go"